# Check calls Received() for async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, nsubstitute

When I run the following code:

```
[Test]
public async Task Can_Test_Update()
{
    var response = await _controller.UpdateAsync(Guid.NewGuid());
    response.Valid.Should().BeTrue();

    _commands.Received().UpdateAsync(
        Arg.Is<Something>(
            l => l.Status == Status.Updated)); 
}
```

If I add "`await`" preceding the "`_commands.Received().UpdateAsync`", it throws a null reference exception.  How can I stop this happening, or is `await` not necessary?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://gist.github.com/HEskandari/8235481).

```
Received.InOrder(async () =>
{
    await _Commands.UpdateAsync(Arg.Is<Lobby>(l => l.Status == Status.Updated));
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need the extra `Received()` within lambda: 
`Received.InOrder(async () => { await _Commands.UpdateAsync(...); })`

Comment: When running the tests, It causing errors: “Expected to receive these calls in order”

Answer (score 12):

When NSubstitute sees an async call it automatically creates a completed task so the await works as you would expect in your code (and not throw a NullReferenceException). In this case that would be the task returned from `_commands.UpdateAsync(Status.Updated))` inside the method you are testing.

The `.Received()` call on the other hand is verifying that the async method was called, that is fully synchronous so it doesn't need to be awaited.

The key thing to remember is that async methods return a `Task`. Calling the async method and returning the task is fully synchronous, you then await the `Task` to know when the asyncronous operation which the task represents is completed.

Comment: Problem is that this then leaves an unsightly error in the console. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48482221/54225) does work but I'd also point out that [moq deals with this situation much more cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136721/542251) if your not set on nsubstitute

Answer (score 12):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31515481/395699) on Stack Overflow, as of NSubstitute version 1.8.3 you can use `await` and it will work as expected, rather than throwing a NullReferenceException.

I've just tried it out as I was on version 1.5.0 and getting the NullReferenceException as you describe, but now I'm on the latest (1.10.0), it's working well.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently you can simply `await` the `Received` method:

```
[Test]
public async Task Can_Test_Update()
{
    var response = await _controller.UpdateAsync(Guid.NewGuid());
    response.Valid.Should().BeTrue();

    await _commands.Received().UpdateAsync(
        Arg.Is<Something>(
            l => l.Status == Status.Updated)); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The  [Jake Ginnivan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31021430/52277) correctly points that for Received await is not required, however compiler doesn’t understand it and shows

> warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the
>   current method continues before the call is completed. Consider
>   applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

The simplest workaround is to suppress warning

```
 #pragma warning disable 4014 //for .Received await is not required, so suppress warning “Consider applying the 'await' operator”
   _publisher.Received(totalNumber).MyMethod(Arg.Any<ParamType>());
 #pragma warning restore 4014
```

Comment: A good reason to use [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart). That handles this problem without having to suppress errors

Comment: @Liam, when team chooses mocking library, there are more than one reason to decide, which one to use.

Comment: @Liam Your answer didn't age well, did it? :)

Comment: @elsueco, what do you mean? The answer is mine, Liam made a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> when i add "await" preceding the "_commands.Received().UpdateAsync",
>   it occurs error null reference

That's because when you don't `await`, the method (`Can_Test_Update`) may end before it actually checks the null value you're passing to the method, which means the test ends. You have a race condition. When you `await` on `UpdateAsync`, the method actually asynchronously waits for the operation to complete, and `UpdateAsync` gets a chance to access the null you're passing to it.

To resolve your error, simply put a breakpoint inside `UpdateAsync` and see which value is passed as null to the method. I suspect `Arg.Is<Something>` is your problem.

Comment: thans Yuval, 
I add "await _controller.UpdateAsync(Guid.NewGuid());" in the content. 
Received() used for checking if _commands.UpdateAsync() is executed,
and _commands.UpdateAsync() only return Task.

Answer (score 0):

If UpdateAsync is a stubbed method, you need to return an empty Task, not null. You can not await a null Task.

Example:

```
receivedObject.Stub(s => s.Update(...)).Return(Task.FromResult(0));
```

**Edit**

The problem is at this line:

```
var mockService = Substitute.For<ICalculationServiceAsync>();
```

Or more exactly, when you call it's method:

```
await _service.Calculate();
```

You create a mock service but you don't stub the method. I'm not sure how to do it in Nunit (we mainly use Rhino, I'll need to check), but you need to stub your Calculate method to return an empty Task (Task.FromResult(0)). By default, stubbed methods return the default return type and default(Task) is null.

About [your gist](https://gist.github.com/HEskandari/8235481): DoSomethingAsync shouldn't be async void. I assume you would want to await it's execution.

Comment: @letitbe: Updated my answer. DoSomethingAsync shouldn't be async void because you can't await it anymore!

Comment: I have tried to mock method  .Returns(Task.FromResult(false));
but still get null reference exception when call Received();.

Comment: in SystemUnderTest.DoSomethingAsync try and see what _service.Calculate returns before you await it. If it's null, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this issue in NSubsittute 1.8.3, it seems its fixed in 1.9.0 version or higher.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34925278)