# Moq framework to test method execute times

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Please look at my code below, the verification always failed. Anyone can help?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private IMyDataService dataService = null;

    public ViewModel(IMyDataService dataService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> filters {get; set;}

    public void ProcessFilters()
    {
        dataService.ProcessFilters(filters);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ProcessFilters_Test()
{
    var mockService = new Mock<IMyDataService>();
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(mockService.Object);
    Dictionary<string,string> filters = null;
    vm.ProcessFilters(filters);
    mockService.Verify(x=>x.ProcessFilters(filters), Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: Your `filters`-variable stays allways null, I assume this is the problem

Comment: I only test if the dataService.ProcessFilters method executed. I don't care what the filters value.

Comment: Without the code of this method we can only guess what goes whrong. Does your code throw an exception? Or does the assert-statement simply fail?

Comment: No, the code execute successfully. Just the Verify test method said: Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: x=>x.ProcessFilters(filters)

Comment: Did you try to debug your test? Should be easy to identify the problem then.

Comment: Sure. in vm.ProcessFilters(filters) method, I can see dataService.ProcessFilters(filters) is executed. But, the verify method couldn't pass.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verify a method call using Moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136674/verify-a-method-call-using-moq). You should setup the method to be verified first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113299/discussion-between-allen4tech-and-himbrombeere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [verify-a-method-call-using-moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136674/verify-a-method-call-using-moq) you have to setup the method before you can verify it:

```
var mockService = new Mock<IMyDataService>();
mockService.Setup(mock => mock.ProcessFilter(null));
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(mockService.Object);
Dictionary<string,string> filters = null;

// Act
vm.ProcessFilters(filters);

// Assert
mockService.Verify(x=>x.ProcessFilters(filters), Times.Once);
```

Furthermore the `ProcessFilters`-method in your `ViewModel` does not expect any parameter. However you have a `filters`-property within your class which is not set (at least not within your provided code). So you either have to add the appropriate parameter to the method-signature or set the property:

```
vm.Filters = filters;
vm.ProcessFilters();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `ProcessFilters` method belonging to the `ViewModel` class does not accept any arguments, so you're not actually calling the method. If you're trying to test whether or not the `ProcessFilters` method belonging to the `ViewModel` class calls the mocked `IMyDataService` exactly once with a `filters` argument that is `null`, then try something like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProcessFilters_Test()
{
    // Arrange.
    var mock = new Mock<IMyDataService>();
    var vm = new ViewModel(mock.Object);

    // Act.
    vm.ProcessFilters();

    // Assert.
    mock.Verify(s => s.ProcessFilters(null), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: As far as I see this is exactly what OP already does, makes no difference if he provides `null` directly or via a variable (`filters`).