# How to Verify the parameters in Moq?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, moq

I am writing test case and getting compile error. Returns is not working in this below statement.

```
    //Moq
    //Error: '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'. This gives error before ".Returns".
    private Mock<ITestDomain> _testDomain;
   //test
    [TestMethod]
    public void PassParams()
    {
    //arrange
    var opentickResponse = new OpenTicketResponse();
    opentickResponse.Tickets.Add(new Ticket { TickId = "ticket123"});
    opentickResponse.Tickets.Add(new Ticket { TickId = "ticket456"});
    
    
    _testDomain.Setup(x => x.OpenTicketing(null)).Returns(openTickResponse);
    //act
    var response = _target.Execute(_request);
    
    //assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response, "response = null");
    Assert.AreEqual("name", response.Ticket.Countryname);
    
    
    _testDomain.Verify(x => x.OpenTicket(null)).Returns(x => (x[0] as OpenTicketRequest).phone.ID == _request.phone.ID && 
        (x[0] as OpenTicketRequest).ActiveContract.IDnumber == _request.ActiveContract.IDnumber);
    }
```

I wrote like this but this shows error. Is the Verify statement wrong?

Comment: "but this shows error" - which error?

Comment: @KlausGütter Operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type 'void'. OpenDocument(null)).Returns   error shows at this dot.

Comment: First of all, I am assuming you are writing this in some good IDEs that should have evidently shown you the reason. Second, you must be exploring the documentations for this Mock before using/applying. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136674/verify-a-method-call-using-moq). If this makes sense to you, and helps, am i winning the bounty ;-) ?

Comment: @Ak777 am not understanding what I missed here. I think the link which you sent I have already seen.

Comment: I mean is this as simple as a typo? Did you forget the `_` before `testDomain.Setup`? Shouldn't it be `_testDomain.Setup`? Also, did you instanciate the Mock? `_testDomain = new Mock<ITestDomain>();`?

Comment: What is _target and _request? Can you please post more code?

Comment: @Viktor _request is passing arguments. mock sample values. _target is passing interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

The Moq Method `Verify` does not return, it throws if the functions it is trying to verify wasn't called on the mock object. It is a void method. So you can't call `a.Verify().Returns` because `a.Verify()` is void. That's the cause of the compile error.

As for what you were actually trying to achieve I'm a bit puzzled, you are testing `target.Execute`, but your code doesn't show you injecting `_testDomain` into `target` so it's basically not used as far as I can tell. Maybe you should check whether Moq really does what you think it does. [Here](https://softchris.github.io/pages/dotnet-moq.html#moq-how-it-works) is a fair starting point.

Answer (score 2):

`Verify` is used to check that a particular method has been called and can be configured to check to amount of times a method was called and the parameters used to call it e.g. the below would check that `OpenDocument()` is called once with `null` as the parameter value:

```
_testDomain.Verify(x => x.OpenDocument(null), Times.Once);
```

`Verify` is not used to check results of method calls. If you want to check the result of a method, you need a test that calls the method, records the result and makes assertions on the result. It can even be done in the same test by doing something like this instead of using `Verify`:

```
var result = _testDomain.OpenDocument(null);
var openDocumentRequest = result[0] as OpenDocumentRequest;
Assert.AreEqual(_request.phone.ID, openDocumentRequest.phone.ID);
Assert.AreEqual(_request.ActiveContract.IDnumber, openDocumentRequest.ActiveContract.IDnumber);
```

Comment: I want to verify the arguments inside by comparing them.

Comment: "If you want to check the result of a method, you need a test that calls the method, records the result and makes assertions on the result" - that should probably be a separate test.

Comment: this is bounty question. can you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 2):

- I'm going to assume this is unit testing.

I see a lot of problems in that code:

1. You are setting up `testDomain` without the underscore `_` but you are asserting `_testDomain` with the underscore. Is there a difference between the two? Why are there 2 of these?
2. You are never mocking the `OpenDocument` method so inside that target it will return `null`.
3. You are mocking a method called `OpenDocumentation`, but you are asserting that `OpenDocument`.
4. I assume your target doesn't just call methods with `null` parameter in there. So instead of mocking them with `null` maybe you want to use something like `It.IsAny<WhatEverOpenDocumentsReceives>()`
5. In unit testing you are focusing on only one unit to test. In your case, your unit is an instance of the target. EVERYTHING else should be mocked.
   If everything else is mocked at some point that means that `_testDomain` / `testDomain` is not real. Your last statement tries to test if a method from testDomain was called and returned some values. I don't think you need to test that a mocked method returned a certain result. Why would you since you are the one mocking it ?

Comment: I think you are almost correct. You mean no need to use Verify statement?

Answer (score 2):

To validate the arguments you can use Callback() functionality.
In your example it could look like:

```cs
    OpenDocumentRequest actualRequest = null;
    _testDomain.Setup(x => x.OpenDocument(It.IsAny<OpenDocumentRequest>()))
        .Callback((OpenDocumentRequest value) => { actualRequest = value; });

    // act
    var response = _target.Execute(_request);

    // validate actual request
    Assert.IsNotNull(actualRequest);
    Assert.AreEqual(_request.phone.ID, actualRequest.phone.ID);
    Assert.AreEqual(_request.ActiveContract.IDnumber, actualRequest.ActiveContract.IDnumber);
```