# Moq - how to test class implementation

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I have a class called AuthManager.  It implements an interface IAuthManager.  The interface has two methods.
AuthorizeTransaction() and
CancelTransaction()

Let say I call AuthorizeTransaction() and it throws an exception, in the catch block I handle exception and call CancelTransaction().

How can I verify with Moq that my CancelTransaction() was called.  I tried this with Mock mock = new Mock().  Then mock.Verify(…) to verify CancelTransaction() method was called.  But I get error Non-override method cannot be verified.  I don’t want to put virtual keyword on the method just so the test can pass.  Is there anyway to verify CancelTransaction() was called upon exception?  Thank you.

Update: I followed the link provided by Michael.  This is my code below.  But my testing is failing because of this error **Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times**

```
            // Arrange
            mockAuth = new Mock<IAuthManager>();
            mockAuth.Setup(mock => mock.CancelAuthorization(It.IsAny<CancelAuthorizationModel>()));

            var auth = new AuthManager(new FakeDataRepo(), fakeDataManager, fakeCardManager(), fakeSearchManager, fakeTokenManager, new fakeConnection(), fakeDataManager);
            var authModel = GenerateModel(
                type: ...........,
                transactionType: ...........,
                transactionNumber: .........);

            try
            {
                // Act
                await auth.AuthorizeTransaction(authModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Assert
                mockAuth.Verify(x => x.CancelTransaction(It.IsAny<CancelTransactionModel>()), Times.Once);
            }
```

Comment: Exactly which class do you want to test and which do you want to mock?

Comment: AuthManager.cs is the class I want to test, it has two methods AuthorizeTransaction() and CancelTransaction().  I have class called AuthSpec.cs which has a test method.  In that test method I want to verify when an exception is thrown in AuthorizeTransaction() method, CancelAuthorization() is called.

Comment: Do I get you right that the implementation class should call its own CancelAuthorization method whenever there is an exception in its own AuthorizeTransaction() method? This is a somewhat unusual design and hardly testable.

Comment: The AuthorizeTransaction() has a try catch block, so if there is an exception, it calls CancelTransaction() method inside the catch block.  I am working on existing code, it could have done better.  There are lot of dependencies for the AuthManager.cs class as you can see in the constructor call.

Comment: Yes, but because it calls its own CancelTransaction() method you cannot verify by providing a mock. Except maybe by observing the actions CancelTransaction does on other (mockble) objects

Comment: I see.  Yes I don't see any way of proving that the CancelTransaction() method was called.  I'll see if I can observer the other actions and maybe check those conditions in my test method.  Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In your test method or test initializer you'll want to perform these setups

```
_mockAuthManager.Setup(am => am.AuthorizeTransaction(It.IsAny<T>()))
                        .Throws(new Exception()); // Can specify exception as well.

_mockAuthManager.SetUp(am => am.CancelTransaction(It.IsAny<T>()))
                        .Returns(It.IsAny<T>())
```

Then during your assertions

```
_mockAuthManager.Verify(am => am.CancelTransaction(It.IsAny<T>()), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Hello Michael, will _mockAuthManager.Setup(...) test my original implementation of the AuthorizeTransaction() method in AuthManager class?

Comment: I am thinking that .Setup(...) will not allow me to test the original method, it mocks the method and I am testing a mock.  Is that right?  If so, I don't want to test a mock implementation of my class.  I want to test the actual implementation of my methods.

Comment: If that is the case, then you are better off just using the actual interface rather than a mock. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136721/15177106) to be insightful

Comment: Michael thanks for that link.  Not sure what I am missing.  I am getting an error.  I updated my post above.  Can you please take a look?